# MySQL Select using REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

I have following values in my mysql table column named color: 1;2;3;11;12

```
id | color
1  | 1;2
2  | 2;11
3  | 1;3
4  | 12
```

I want to use REGEXP to select only those rows from the table which have color 1.

When i use simple expression

```
color REGEXP '1'
```

it also selects rows which have values 11 or 12 whereas i am looking for those with value 1 only. So when i use above expression it show me all 4 rows as shown in the example above where as i want it to show me rows with id 1 and 3 only.

Comment: Your database is violates the first normal form. You are saving multiple values in one column (color). Please normalize your database.

Comment: I think this is not the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [to use word-delimiters on either side of the 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to isolate it:

```
color REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
REGEXP '^1;|;1;|;1$'
```

If I'm not wrong this will either find a 1 at the start followed by a semicolon or a 1 between two semicola, or a single 1 after a semicolon. This should pretty much be it.